# How to adjust the height of content div?

Tags: css

I have header div, navigate div and content at my app. I want to adjust the height of div content to the content into and using scroller if it is needed.

The Css of the div:

```
// the parent div
.bookManage {
    height: 100%;
}

.books {
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 60%; // it is work only for specific number of elements. When I added more elements the height doesn't increase.
}
```

I also try:

```
// the parent div
.bookManage {
    height: 100%;
}

.books {
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: XXpx \ XX%; // the size of the div doesn't increase 
}
```

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: What does XX indicate? Is it a number ?

Comment: You should inclure an html snippet of what you want to achieve

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy yes.

Comment: @abumalick I added a snippent